# Weird SQL error

Tags: sql-server

am seeing the error logs below on my SQL server, I'm not sure if they are related to trace flag 3604. I also see something to do with memory dump as well. Please advice.

```
 15:15:53.81 spid594   m_pageId = (1:1172094)    m_headerVersion = 1       m_type = 2|0
 15:15:53.81 spid594   m_typeFlagBits = 0x0      m_level = 0               m_flagBits = 0x0|0
 15:15:53.81 spid594   m_objId = 954538534       m_indexId = 6             m_prevPage = (1:1102845)|0
 15:15:53.81 spid594   m_nextPage = (1:1172095)  pminlen = 21              m_slotCnt = 212|0
 15:15:53.81 spid594   m_freeCnt = 2584          m_freeData = 5880         m_reservedCnt = 0|0
 15:15:53.81 spid594   m_lsn = (119582:10616:47) m_xactReserved = 0        m_xdesId = (0:753243376)|0
 15:15:53.81 spid594   m_ghostRecCnt = 0         m_tornBits = -2147483127  |0
 15:15:53.81 spid594   |0
Allocation Status|0
-----------------|0
 15:15:53.81 spid594   GAM (1:1022464) = ALLOCATED                         |0
 15:15:53.81 spid594   SGAM (1:1022465) = NOT ALLOCATED                    |0
 15:15:53.81 spid594   PFS (1:1164672) = 0x40 ALLOCATED   0_PCT_FULL       DIFF (1:1022470) = CHANGED|0
 15:15:53.81 spid594   ML (1:1022471) = NOT MIN_LOGGED                     |0
 15:15:53.81 spid594   |0
DATA:|0
-----|0
 15:15:53.81 spid594   |0
Memory Dump @0x3CFF0000|0
-----------------------|0
 15:15:53.81 spid594   3CFF0000:  01020000 00000600 fdd31000 01001500 7fe21100  ....................|0
 15:15:53.81 spid594   3CFF0014:  0100d400 261ae538 180af816 7ee21100 01000000  ....&..8....~.......|0
 15:15:53.81 spid594   3CFF0028:  1ed30100 78290000 2f000000 f094e52c 00000000  ....x)../......,....|0
 15:15:53.81 spid594   3CFF003C:  09020080 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ....................|0
 15:15:53.81 spid594   3CFF0050:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 1a2c0d00  .................,..|0
 15:15:53.83 spid594   3CFF0064:  009c0300 00e30300 0097f79a 10000000 00040000  ....................|0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trace flag 3604 simply redirects DBCC command output to the client (instead of the error log).
It looks like someone has been running the DBCC PAGE command to take a closer look at individual database pages, but forgot that output gets redirected to the error log, and then ran in the 3604 trace flag to view the output.

Answer (score 0):

@Eric213 already answered your question. To add more to it :

-- find out what traceflags are enabled on the instance

```
dbcc tracestatus(-1)
```

--- to Turn off the traceflag :

```
dbcc traceoff (traceNumber)
```

---  To disable the trace flag globally, you have to use

```
dbcc traceoff (traceNumber, -1)
```